# Code coverage for $state changing service

Tags: coffeescript, angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

I can't manage to provide code coverage for this $state changing service:

```
($state) ->
  @$inject = ["$state"]

  -> $state.go "home.about"
```

This is my test which fails the last two expects:

```coffee
mock = require "mock"

    describe "goHomeService", ->
      goHomeService = $state = undefined
      beforeEach mock.module "main"
      beforeEach mock.inject (_goHomeService_, _$state_) ->
        goHomeService = _goHomeService_
        $state = _$state_
      it "should chage $state to 'home.about'", ->
        spy = jasmine.createSpy $state, "go"
        expect($state.current.name).not.toEqual "home.about"
        expect($state.go).toEqual jasmine.any Function
        goHomeService()
        expect($state.current.name).toEqual "home.about" 
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith "home.about"
```

Comment: typo chage should be change

Comment: ? I can't get what you  want to tell me